# Modify values before remote check in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form that has a 2 textboxes. PageName and RouteToken. RouteToken is validated remotely against database. It works great, problem that I have a blur function on PageName that "copies" value to RouteToken. That works til I, with both textboxes filled with same info, go to PageName and delete a couple of chars and then tab out click somewhere. Randomly it works, randomly few chars get deleted in RouteToken, depending on how fast or slow I do it.

I have added this (voodooo) to my edit page to "mirror" things and making the pagename url friendly:

```
$("#PageName").change(function (e)
 {
     e.preventDefault();

     var routeToken = parseUrl($("#PageName").val());

     $("#RouteToken").val(routeToken);
});
```

In view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PageName)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RouteToken)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RouteToken)
```

Remote check:

```
public JsonResult CheckRouteToken(Page page)
{
    var r = _contentRep.GetRoute(page.RouteToken);

    bool isValid = ((r == null || page.PageID == r.PageID);

    return Json(isValid, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

Is there some way of modifying this so my function and the validation can work together? I would prefer somehow to "on blur" have the routeToken filled with some server side when pageName textbox loses focus. Or some modification to my js so it work.

Any pointers, ideas or modifications?